# Android Loader, why does restartLoader not refresh my Listview?

Tags: android, cursor, android-cursoradapter, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I am trying to do the following

```
1) Activity with a List view 
2) Talks to content ContentProvider
3) Populates the ListView with contents of Cursor 
4) User can then add new items to database  
5) After each item is added I want to refresh the list view to show the updated items.
```

Everything upto point 5 works.

So I need help with restarting the Loader after the item has been added.

So after the data has been added to the database I am calling:

> `getLoaderManager().restartLoader(ID, null, MyFragment.this);`

And in the Loader methods I simply do:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onCreateLoader");
    cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), 
      MyContract.CONTENT_URI, 
      null, null, null, "_id ASC");

      return cursorLoader;


}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {

        adapter.swapCursor(cursor); //swap the new cursor in.


}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    adapter.swapCursor(null);

}
```

When this is called, the ListView blanks out.
All previous items in the list disappear.

If I go out of my activity and back into again the SimpleCursorAdapter will populate the ListView with the added items in the database.

So I know they have been added correctly.

But it is not displaying after I call restartLoader.

Does anyone know how I can refresh the listView using the Loader ?

Should I call something after

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, null, MyFragment.this);`
```

Or do I need to something more clever in onLoaderReset method ?

Any tips and pointers please ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: you dont need to do that, all you need is a well behaving ContentProvider

Comment: you mean you dont recommend using a Loader ??

Comment: no, you have to use a Loader, the point is to create a ContentProvider that notifies about any changes done inside